# Ansible Reload Cisco Devices Hangs

Tags: ansible, cisco-ios

I have a task that reloads a number of Cisco Routers and Cisco Firewalls. For some reason the playbook always hangs at this task after the playbook have already reloaded the first device. The reload command is actually sent to the second device and I can see the device restart but the task will eventually fail.

Output:

```json
Task [Reload Host Device]
fatal: [firewall2]: FAILED! => {"changed: false, "msg": "command timeout triggered, timeout value is 30 secs. \nsee the timeout setting options in the Network Debug and Troubleshooting Guide."} ...ignoring
```

Task:

```yaml
- name: Reload Host Device 
  cli_command:
    command: "reload"
    prompt:
      - "Proceed with reload?"
    answer:
      - "y"
  ignore_errors: yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the given description, task and error message

```
command timeout triggered ... see the timeout setting options in the Network Debug and Troubleshooting Guide.
```

the devices which Ansible are connects to are going to restart faster than Ansible and the module `cli_command` can maintain his own connection. Meaning, close and disconnect the session.

According the [Command Reference](https://www.cisco.com/E-Learning/bulk/public/tac/cim/cib/using_cisco_ios_software/cmdrefs/reload.htm) and [Cisco Router: Auto restart in x seconds](https://superuser.com/a/1080520/754490) you may try with

```yaml
- name: Schedule Host Device Reload in 1 min
  cli_command:
    command: "reload in 1"
    prompt:
      - "Proceed with reload?"
    answer:
      - "y"
  register: result

- name: Show result
  debug:
    var: result
```

**Further Reading**

An other approach which was used in the past for Linux systems

- [How to automate system reboots using the Ansible?](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/automate-reboot-ansible)

Comment: Thank you! This make total sense. I made the update and I'm not seeing any errors within the ansible console output.

Comment: So the first time executing the playbook after the update, I didn't see any errors as I stated earlier. However, running the tasks ever since still result into a failure for this task (the command is still being sent to the device however)